# Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile for a mobile web app. When I try to run MyFunction that is set on a onclick attribute then I get an error in the console that

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Product</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>



<!--Generation Script Starts here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 4; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

function makeid1()
{
    var text1 = "";
    var possible = "123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 1; i++ )
        text1 += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text1;
}

function makeid2()
{
    var text2 = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for( var i=0; i < 1; i++ )
        text2 += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text2;
}

function makeid3()
{
    var text3 = "";
    var possible = "123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 2; i++ )
        text3 += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text3;
}

function myFunction()
{
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="D01E-BOA0-" + makeid() + "-" + makeid1() + makeid2() + makeid3();
}

</script>
<!-- Generation Script Ends Here -->

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-iconshadow="false" data-inline="true">Home</a>
    <h1>Product</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">


    <p id="demo" style="text-align:center;"></p>

    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Generate!" data-theme="b">
</div><!-- /content -->


</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you importing jQuery twice?

Comment: In your actual code, you declared `myFunction` and call `myFunction()`, but the error message you posted says `Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined`. Note the capital "M". JavaScript is case-sensitive. Make sure you aren't mixing those up

Comment: It works for me without any error. Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/VTg9q/).

Comment: It works on my computer but it messes up when I execute it on android. Here is the picture of the error log http://gyazo.com/5784e0b14b7306dc746fae530ef8c9d4

Comment: @user2405869 What about this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/VTg9q/1/)?

Comment: @NOX not working on android.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will help or not, wrap all your code into document ready, and
handle the `click` of button with jQuery:

```
<input type="button" id="generate" value="Generate!" data-theme="b">
```

```
$('#generate').on('click', function () {
    $("#demo").html("D01E-BOA0-" + makeid() + "-" + makeid1() + makeid2() + makeid3());
});
```

The full code:

```
$(function () {

    function makeid() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "123456789";

        for( var i=0; i < 4; i++ ) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text;
    }

    function makeid1() {
        var text1 = "";
        var possible = "123456789";

        for( var i=0; i < 1; i++ ) {
            text1 += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text1;
    }

    function makeid2() {
        var text2 = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for( var i=0; i < 1; i++ ) {
            text2 += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text2;
    }

    function makeid3() {
        var text3 = "";
        var possible = "123456789";

        for( var i=0; i < 2; i++ ) {
            text3 += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text3;
    }

    $('#generate').on('click', function () {
        $("#demo").html("D01E-BOA0-" + makeid() + "-" + makeid1() + makeid2() + makeid3());
    });

});
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/VTg9q/1/) to test it on android.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problems:

1. Add a listener for onLoad to your body:

   `<body onLoad="fireItUp()">`
2. Use the called method to add an event listener for cordova's deviceready:

   ```
   function fireItUp() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   }
   ```
3. Use the call back method to bind your events to jquery mobiles 'tap' event (You might want to give the button a id or class, since this binds to all input elements, which is probably undesired):

   ```
   function onDeviceReady() {            
       jQuery(input).bind('tap',function(event){
       myFunction();
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: sorry :/ I didn't understand. I for the fireItUp() and cordova's event listener but what am I supposed to do with step 3? :S

Comment: Just put it in your Javascript. It is the method, which will be called after the device is ready. Then it binds jquery mobiles own version of touch event to all input elements in your html. This is why I said, you might want to add an id to your click element and then do: jQuery("#myClickElement").bind(...

Comment: it's still not working. Can we please talk on skype or something? It is a lot easier to troubleshoot this that way.

Comment: Actually this platform is more about giving advice and helping you learn rather then delivering ready made solutions for specific problems . I suggest you read some tutorials, the cordova guides and start over again, eventually you'll figure it out yourself and that will be quite more rewarding.